# Show/hide nearby elements by class using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, toggle

I am attempting to toggle the display of two divs that are in a nearby element (show one and hide the other). There are multiple similar elements on the page, so I can't use IDs.

This is what I'm trying, which is obviously incorrect:

JQUERY

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".innerContainer").next(".summary").toggle();
    $(this).next(".innerContainer").next(".details").toggle();
});
```

CSS

```
.buttonClass {
    cursor: pointer; 
}
.summary {
    display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="buttonClass"><img src="images/buttons/expandButton.png" /></div>
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="summary">Summary here.</div>
        <div class="details">Details here.</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="outerContainer">
    <div class="buttonClass"><img src="images/buttons/expandButton.png" /></div>
    <div class="innerContainer">
        <div class="summary">Summary here.</div>
        <div class="details">Details here.</div>
    </div>
</div>

... more of the same
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check out the documentation on [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) and [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `find()`

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".innerContainer").find(".summary").toggle();
    $(this).next(".innerContainer").find(".details").toggle();
});
```

or, because the button and targets have one shared parent, you can use `closest()` on `.outerContainer`

```
$(".buttonClass").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".outerContainer").find(".summary").toggle();
    $(this).closest(".outerContainer").find(".details").toggle();
});
```